# Safari web page saved to home screen stuck in standalone mode

Tags: html, ios, safari, progressive-web-apps

We've been working on a web app and did some work to make it more PWAesque, so we added `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` to our `<head />`.

This ended up being more problematic as we hadn't thought to implement our own navigation UI (back and forward etc) and it appears that as soon as you exit you lose your logged in session.

So this ended up negatively impacting experience and we've decided to remove `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`.

Easy, right?

Nope.

Even with the removal of this meta tag and new installations to the Home Screen (and on different devices where it was not previously installed) it continues to open in standalone mode rather than in Safari.

I've scoured Google pretty hard but maybe I'm not searching the right terms.

Is there a step that I've missed? Has any one encountered this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a manifest file? Are you asking for "standalone" there?

Comment: Yes! I hadn't thought of that, I'll see if that fixes the issue. It might get tricky as a I think we want to support standalone on android. We can figure that out later though.

Comment: Just to follow up, that was the case! Thanks McMurphy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that it was in our `manifest.json` file.